# Get fingerprint reader working on mbp?

Tags: mac, fingerprint-reader

I recently got my macbook pro 2018 working with ubuntu, specifically the build from t2linux. Is there any way to get the fingerprint reader working? fingerprint-gui is depreciated and GNOME doesn't seem to support the mac.

Comment: Nope. Apple has not made the drivers available and all attempts to reverse engineer it (so far) have been incomplete.